# Mod rewrite exclude one route from https redirect

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

need help with htaccess file. I tried many variants of redirect to HTTPS, but found only one working example, another examples return too many redirects.
My rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It work good, but I have one route that use styles and script from another site, that don't not have HTTPS. I need for this route use only HTTP, but I can't exclude this route from HTTPS redirect, have you any ideas?

Comment: do you want to exclude a directory that contains js and css or any file ended with css & js?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just replace example.com with your domain. It should work

Comment: Can you post apache.conf file?